# Распечатать все части слова, начинающиеся с заданного символа на языке Turbo Pascal

Tags: алгоритм, turbopascal

Не могу придумать алгоритм, который будет из слова выводить части этого слова начинающиеся с произвольного введенного символа.
Например: слово "Evanescent", при введенной "E" должен вывести:
Evanescent
escent
ent
Спасибо.

upd.
Это учебное задание я пытался решить сам, но застрял на непонимании от куда берется последняя строчка с последним повторяющимся словом

```
    var
    str,let,tmp:string;
    i,k,j:integer;
    x:array[1..50] of integer;

    begin
    readln(str);
    readln(let);
    tmp:=str;
    j:=1;
    while pos(let,tmp) > 0 do begin
        x[j]:=pos(let,tmp);
        tmp[pos(let,tmp)]:='0';
        inc(j);
    end;
    for i:=1 to j do begin
       for k:=x[i] to 50 do begin
           write(str[k]);
       end;
    writeln;
    end;
    end.
```

[image: Результат работы]

Comment: Мне интересно, люди которые ставят минусы имеют сверх разум? сами то вы сможете это сделать?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: Отозвал тревогу.

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
var
str,let,tmp:string;
i,k,j:integer;
x:array[1..50] of integer;

begin
readln(str);
readln(let);
tmp:=str;
j:=1;
while pos(let,tmp) > 0 do begin
    x[j]:=pos(let,tmp);
    tmp[pos(let,tmp)]:='0';
    inc(j);
end;
for i:=1 to j-1 do begin
   for k:=x[i] to length(str) do begin
       write(str[k]);
   end;
writeln;
end;
end.
```

Слегка подправил цикл